# Normalizing addresses in UK

Tags: normalization, street-address

I have been going through different sites like [crunchy data solutions](https://blog.crunchydata.com/blog/quick-and-dirty-address-matching-with-libpostal) and this [python project](https://postal-address.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) but all of them seems to be focused in US. I would like to know if someone knows the best way to normalize address for matching criteria coming from different resources. I have been researching in old questions but I couldn't find any answer or question focused in UK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment the closest I am is for a single line address concatenate all the fields address realted for then:

```
UPDATE table
SET concatenate_fields = replace(concatenate_fields, ',', '');
```

this provided a single line not separated by commas then:

```
UPDATE table
SET concatenate_fields = upper (concatenate_fields);
```

This provided a single line all in upper cases and not commas. I have done the same for all the tables which I need to match for the address till having some mismatch.